# Maximum Size of SharedPreferences class

Tags: android

I want to save a lot of strings with `SharedPreferences` class . 
These strings are quit long. 
I really want to know the maximum length of a string that can be save in shared preferences in android.And Also How much size of data i can store in This `SharedPrefernces` class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***As per android architecture there is no such limit to store data in SharedPreference***. Better way is to  **database (SQLite)** when you have to deal with huge amount of data

Answer (score 2):

I read somewhere that there is no hard limit other than Integer.MAX_VALUE ( maximal string length).  But it is not advisable to store that much on shared preferences, as this is XML file which must be parsed and you will have a problems while parsing it.

I used to store about 50-100KBytes  there.   It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer obtained manually is: maximum Unicode symbol's size is 5`657`632 symbols (or from [0 to 5657631]) in my case. It's some about 2.7MB for SharedPReference.Editor .

Rather large storage.
You ca use this size twice:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c)
context.getSharedPreferences("<key>", <Mode>);
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course is't limit for SharedPreferences but if system won't have enough memory it is one first stuff what DELETE it, you remember it.